# Is an air gun allowed on the flight to Australia?

Tags: australia, firearms

I bought an air gun in Visakhapatnam and I was wondering if I could take an air gun to home to Australia in my checked-in baggage?

Comment: There are different types of "air guns", notably spring-loaded and gas loaded. Those may very well be covered by different regulations for air transport, so it may help if you specify as much about the item you bought as reasonably possible. (Import regulations once it *arrives* in Australia are an entirely different issue, but not less important.)

Answer (score 3):

Airlines *may* permit you to carry an air gun as checked baggage, but policies may differ from airline to airline.  For example, [Qantas](https://www.qantas.com/travel/airlines/dangerous-goods/global/en#ammunition-cartridges-for-weapons-andor-firearms) permits firearms (including airsoft guns) to be carried under certain conditions.

However, an air gun is classified as a firearm for the purposes of the [Customs (Prohibited Imports) Regulations 1956](https://www.legislation.gov.au/Details/F2016C00795).  You will not be able to import the item without the appropriate [gun licence, acquisition permit and police certification](https://www.ag.gov.au/LegalSystem/Firearms/Pages/default.aspx).